# Execute silent sqlplus in background from bash program

Tags: bash, oracle, sqlplus

I want to know if its posible to execute in background a sqlplus like this

`sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<IN
select 1 from dual;
IN`

I know that I can call a .sql file with nohup sqlplus ... @file.sql & but I want use the <

Something like this

`nohup (sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<IN
select 1 from dual;
IN) &`

Or similar...

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
(
nohup sqlplus -s "/ as sysdba" <<IN
select 1 from dual;
IN
) &
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
while [ 1 ]
do
sqlplus -s <<EOF
user/password@SID
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT SQL.SQLCODE
set feedback off
set serveroutput on
select 1 from dual;
EOF
sql_status=$?
if [ $sql_status -eq 0 ] 
then
.
.
.
done
```

Comment: That isn't running in the background?

Comment: yep, had to add ==>  "nohup ./filename.ksh &"  Thanks for point out Alex. :)